# Hudson how to deploy multiple webapps?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I have install the Deploy Plugin on Hudson.

Is it possible to fill "Deploy war/ear to a container" field with two webapps. What is the convention ? Using ; or , or space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the plugin documentation:

*This plugin takes **a** war/ear file and deploys that to a running remote application server at the end of a build.*

So it seems that it can't do more than one.

Comment: The documentaion is not really good. But its seems strange that it can't deploy multiple webapps